# How to call custom filters in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework, filter, htmlpurifier

I want to use htmlpurifier on my website, but can't figure out how to load my filter in the view. I've added my filter the way described [in the first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646827/include-htmlpurifier-with-zend-loader).

I want to be able to call it from my view with something like `$this->filter($content)` Any suggestions how I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a two step process:

1. Write an actual Zend_Filter implementation of HTMLPurifier (done, answer in the question you mentioned)
2. Write a [view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html)

It will look like this:

```
class My_View_Helper_Purify extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
   public function purify($value)
   {
       $filter = new My_Filter_HtmlPurifier();

       return $filter->filter($value);
   }
}
```

Don't forget to add your custom view helper path:

```
    $view->addHelperPath(
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/My/View/Helper',
        'My_View_Helper_'
    );
```

And later in any of your view scripts:

```
<?= $this->purify($text) ?>
```

Comment: Using a view helper makes a lot of sense, I didn't think of that. I'll try it out. Thank you!

Comment: +1 for the clean explanation. Although the OP was specific in his question that he wanted to filter on output, it's worth noting that filtering on input - whatever the source - is probably worth some consideration, as well.

Comment: Is it not enough to escape everything when inserting it in the database?

Comment: There are two schools of thought on that. Some say you should filter as much as possible before even writing to the db to minimize the risk of anything evil getting in there. Others say just escape it, but leave the data as intact as possible. This will give you better scalability as it's easier to adapt to possible future needs of the data. Also, depending on in what context you output the data, what constitutes "evil" characters varies. E.g. sometimes it's ok to leave tags alone, while other times you need to filter.

Comment: One model I've used is to have two columns, one for raw content, the other for filtered content. You could even implement a type of lazy-loading for filtering the content with that model.